# Issues in text update and image in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am so tried When i update my text fields and also update image then update successfully but when in update only text fields or not update image then my old image is deleted from the database in Codeigniter.

**controller**

```
function blog_walk_update($id){

    $this->_checkAuthorized(self::CATEGORY_ID,'w');
    $_POST['id'] = $id; 
    //start
    if($_FILES['file_name']!=""){
        $storeFolder = './photo/uploads/';
        $pics = array();
        $file = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $storeFolder .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $file;
        if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){
            array_push($pics,array("img"=>"/".$targetFile));
        }
        $_POST['file_name'] = $file;
    }else{
        $_POST['file_name'] = $file;
    }

    /////end

    $this->blog->blog_walk_update($_POST);
    redirect('/admin/blog/walk');
}
```

**model**

```
function blog_walk_update($data){
            $id = addslashes($data['id']);
            $t_name = addslashes($data['t_name']);
            $t_desp = addslashes($data['t_desp']);
            $file_name = addslashes($data['file_name']);
            $area_id = addslashes($data['area_id']);
            return $this->db->query("UPDATE walk_area  SET t_name = '$t_name', t_desp = '$t_desp', area_id = '$area_id',file_name = '$file_name'  WHERE id = '$id'");
        }
```

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Image</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url()."photo/uploads/".$walks->file_name  ?>" style ="width: 100px;">    
        <input type="file" value="<?= $walks->file_name; ?>" name="file_name" id="file" /><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what was the issue...?

Comment: issue is that brother i update my text fields and not update image then my text fields are update but my img is delete in database

Comment: i want my old image is not delete  when i update my text fields

Comment: Change - `$_FILES['file_name']!=""` to `$_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']!=""`

Comment: Shouldn't you be loading blog model before using it? in - `$this->blog->blog_walk_update($_POST);` ?

Comment: Mr. Blue not working brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing image in image tag so keep file field value blank

```
<input type="file" value="" name="file_name" id="file" /><br/>
```

and check value in post data. When you change image you will get the field value in post data

```
function blog_walk_update($data){

$id = addslashes($data['id']);

$t_name = addslashes($data['t_name']);

$t_desp = addslashes($data['t_desp']);

$area_id = addslashes($data['area_id']);

if(isset($data['file_name']) && $data['file_name']!=''){

$file_name = addslashes($data['file_name']);
    return $this->db->query("UPDATE walk_area  SET t_name = '$t_name', t_desp = '$t_desp', area_id = '$area_id',file_name = '$file_name'  WHERE id = '$id'");

}else{

    return $this->db->query("UPDATE walk_area  SET t_name = '$t_name', t_desp = '$t_desp', area_id = '$area_id'  WHERE id = '$id'");

} 

}
```

Comment: If you want to use validation then use java script to validate image